# Best way to migrate ef to ef core without creating extra migration files

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I am working on a migration project for MVC to Angular/WebApi.

Few features have been migrated and now my company thinks we should migrate WebApi to .net core, leaving MVC project as it is.

If we do this, we will have 2 projects pointing to same database. Database is created using Code First approach.

**Could there be an approach where I can migrate to ef core without creating extra migration files.**

I understand there are many features of ef which is not in ef core fluent api yet like N2N relationships.

I am assuming as there are 2 applications pointing to same database using code first, having different migration files will create conflicts.

We can't stop using MVC(.net framework) project yet since not all features are migrated yet.

Please suggest the best way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does each app use mostly the same tables? If so, pick one app to be in charge of managing the database schema and disable migrations in the other one. If you want to use the EF Core app to manage the schema, see the guidance in issue [#2167](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2167) for bootstrapping the migrations.

If each app mostly uses its own tables, pick an owner for the few shared tables and exclude them in the migrations of the other app. Without issue [#2725](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2725), this means manually deleting any operations that get scaffolded for the tables.